# How to choose a starting value in a dropdown in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a dropdown at a specific cell and assigned values to them. However I do not want to show a blank value at default. What code should I use to set the default value of the dropdown to value 500 (not the positions values of the dropdownlist)? There is this link [Can I set an Excel ComboBox to have a default value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685120/can-i-set-an-excel-combobox-to-have-a-default-value) that was given to me before but this is not what I want  because I am not looking at a validation list.
I have tried -

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Combo Box 1").ControlFormat
    .value = 500
End With
```

but it does not work. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I have linked you to that question, but have you scrolled down to the [second](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31685347/9758194) answer?

Comment: @JvdV that answer is for ActiveX, but this question is about form control (judging by the sample code) and in this case the answer is probably: not possible.

Comment: hi @JvdV, do u mean the ComboBox1.Text = "SomeText" answer? How do I apply it to my case? What does ComboBox1 refer to actually? Thanks for helping

Comment: @BrakNicku, it's possible with the second answer in the link. You can't set `.Value` of a `ComboBox` but you can set `.Text`. Disadvantage would be that you'll end up with that same text, even when you choose another value.

Comment: @HoJunHong, I've tried to explain below.

Comment: yup it is a form control dropdown rather than an activex, thanks for pointing that out @BrakNicku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little more difficult than I thought at first. If you are talking about a `Form` control instead of `ActiveX` you want to set your `.Text` property (just as per linked answer).

However, once you have set your `.Text` property you'll end up changing values but no visual change in your `ComboBox`. One way to overcome this is a `.OnAction` refering to a `Sub` to change that `.Text` property again according to it's `.Value`. And because `.Value` on its turn would return the `Index` we can use that on the `.List` property.

Below a sample code to replicate what I'm talking about:

```
Sub Test()

Dim Bx As Object

'Add ComboBox for testing
Set Bx = Worksheets("Sheet1").DropDowns.Add(0, 0, 100, 15)
Bx.Name = "Combo Box 1"

'Add values to box for testing
Bx.AddItem 100
Bx.AddItem 200
Bx.AddItem 300
Bx.AddItem 400
Bx.AddItem 500

'Create the possibility to change .Text property according to .Value
Bx.OnAction = "StandardVal"

'Set standard value
Bx.Text = 500

End Sub

Sub StandardVal()

With Worksheets("Sheet1").DropDowns("Combo Box 1")
    .Text = .List(.Value)
End With

End Sub
```

In the case of OP, he can set `.Text` property instead of `.Value` and assign a macro (for example the above sample macro "StandardVal") to the `ComboBox`

Comment: great! it seems to be working but when i tried to change the .text to .value, there was an error of application or object-defined error.

Comment: @HoJunHong, It appears you not fully understanding what I meant, but if you got it working then that's great =).

Comment: hi @JvdV, sorry I have another problem now. When i use the .Text = .List(.Value), does my dropdown values become a string? I cant seem to use those values to filter when i try to put .text into my codes.
eg - Worksheets("Summary").Range("$A$11:$A$" & rend).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array(.Text), Operator:=xlFilterValues

Comment: is it possible to convert it back to a number? @JvdV

Comment: Use .List(.Value) for that @HoJunHong